# Apache Active Workers and Hits per Second

Tags: mysql, zabbix, gentoo

We are using 2 AppServer with an Idle Workload of 10 Apache Workers and and 5 Hits per Second.

These Servers got 12 CPUs and 8GB of RAM. Monitoring is accessed by Zabbix. My question about this is - are these Servers way to much for the traffic we gernerate? And equals max_connections (we have 500 set)with active workers?

We have the monitoring, but do not know what the max really is and the hoster will not answer us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it "too much"? Well only you can answer that. Too much is typically not a problem aside from cost, but that's for you to work out.

Comment: Well it´s a simple question. Are 2 big Appserver with that Idle too much. Your comment helps not a single bit. Thanks anyways for wasting my and your time. Obviously we want to save some money - these cost like 300-400$ a month.

Comment: You're not understanding me. In computing, "too much" doesn't typically cause problems unless you think you are spending too much money on the resources. None of us can help you sort out if your budget is too tight. If you are happy with what you're paying and the servers perform well, then just leave it. What more could you possibly expect us to say?

Comment: Well there is nothing about workers and Hits per Second comparing to Server Size. What is recommended. If they perform good, doesn´t mean it is necessary - maybe we need only one. Anyways, you won´t help or even try so we just shut it down I guess and see....

Comment: Right, which is where the capacity planning recommendations come in, as laid out in the question linked above.

Comment: And please, believe me, I *am* helping you in the best possible way here. There is no objective answer to your question. If there was, I'd be glad to answer it. The best I can do is point you in the right direction and recommend that you undertake a capacity planning exercise, and that you delineate clearly your requirements, and then ensure that they're getting met. That's all we can do here. If you need guidance through that process, hire someone to help you out.